# AlamofireObjectMapper Resulting in nil

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

So I'm working with a weather API:
https://api.darksky.net/forecast/88d117d813f2014a1ce7f3de6a00c720/50.909698,-1.404351

The thing I want to achieve is getting all the precipIntensity from each minute into an array. This way I can make a graph where the Y is the precipIntensity and the X is array.count (which would count up to 61 with this API).

So this is my code in the ViewController:

```
func downloadWeatherDetails(completed: DownloadComplete) {
    // Alamofire Download
    let currentWeatherURL = URL(string: WeatherURL)!
    Alamofire.request(currentWeatherURL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<WeatherResponse>) in

        let Forecast = response.result.value
        if let minutelyForecast = Forecast?.minutelyForecast {
            for forecast in minutelyForecast {
                print(forecast.time)
                print(forecast.precipIntensity)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And my Class file is as follows:

```
class WeatherResponse: Mappable {
    var summary: String!
    var minutelyForecast: [Forecast]?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        summary <- map["minutely.summary"]
        minutelyForecast <- map["minutely.data"]
    }
}

class Forecast: Mappable {
    var time: String!
    var precipIntensity: String!

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        time <- map["time"]
        precipIntensity <- map["precipIntensity"]
    }
}
```

However the print(forecast.precipIntensity) prints out nil, 61 times.

1. How do I get this info?
2. And how can I put it into an array to make it into a graph and continue with my work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you **want/need** to use `ObjectMapper` ? If you are considering about migrating to swift 4, you could use `Codable` instead and remove `ObjectMapper` as a third-party dependency

Comment: @nathan I haven't heard of Codable? Last project I was working on I used Object Mapper + Alomofire to get data from API's so I figured it was still a good way to go.

Comment: Updated answer with fix to your problem + 2 solutions using Codable. If you want to learn more about Codable/JSONEncoder/JSONDecoder check other questions with the corresponding tags. It's quite easy to get started, since it requires only one line of code for simple JSON structures

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code was that `time` and `precipIntensity` aren't String values, but numbers.

```
class Forecast: Mappable {
    var time: Int!
    var precipIntensity: Double!
    ...
}
```

Extracting precipitation data :

```
func downloadWeatherDetails(completed: DownloadComplete) {
    // Alamofire Download
    let currentWeatherURL = URL(string: WeatherURL)!
    Alamofire.request(currentWeatherURL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<WeatherResponse>) in

        let Forecast = response.result.value
        if let minutelyForecast = Forecast?.minutelyForecast {
            // Data is already sorted from the API
            // but you could be sure nothing happened while decoding
            // by using `sorted()`
            let minutelyPrecipIntensity = minutelyForecast
                .sorted { $0.time < $1.time }
                .flatMap { $0.precipIntensity }
        }

    }
}
```

Edit: Removed Codable answer

Comment: I don't see how this helps me getting the precipIntensity info from the API into an array.

Comment: `minutelyForecast` is already an array, which contains the weather data ordered ASC by time (from NOW until NOW + 60 min)

Comment: If you still want to extract only `precipitationData`, you can use `minutelyPrecipIntensity`

Comment: Ye but of minutelyForecast I only want the precipIntensity and put them into a new array. That way I get an array filled with the info of the rain, then I can make a graph out of it.

Comment: `minutelyPrecipIntensity` (not `minutelyForecast`) is an array which only has precipitationData, as stated in your 2nd question

Comment: Contextual closure type '(Forecast) -> Bool' expects 1 argument, but 2 were used in closure body, I get that error.

Comment: Fixed "typo" (sorted instead of filter)

Comment: Cool! Finally my output is: [Optional(0.0), Optional(0.0), Optional(0.0), ... ], Guess it's dry now haha. Is the Optional just something the outputter shows for itself? Cause I want the array to be full of Doubles or Int, basically numbers so I can use it to create the graph with. Do you know more about this?

Comment: You can use flatMap instead of map, to return only non-optionals (there will be none in your case)

Comment: Sweet my output is now: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...] So I figure I can append this now into a new array :D Finally haha